# How to force dependencies to be installed from local directory

Tags: go, glide-golang

I have an app hosted in Heroku, and I use glide to collect dependencies when deploying the app. The problem is that I have one library, namely, `gonum.org/v1/gonum`, that cannot be downloaded the standard way. Is it possible to somehow force glide to use pre-downloaded version of package instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you are vendoring your dependencies before deploying to heroku, you should be able to place the pre-downloaded version of the dependency directly in the vendor folder instead.

Glide also support `repo` (see the [documentation](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glide.yaml/)) which allows you to tell glide which repo to find the code in. You could push the code to a private (or public) github repo and configure your `glide.yaml` file to point at that repo.